# Primefaces Timeline NumberFormatException (NaN) on mobile

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm working with primefaces (6.1) timeline and I'm getting an `NumberFormatException (NaN)` on mobile (Chrome in Android) when I double click (touch) any of the group rows to add a new event.

In desktop it works without a problem, and in Firefox for Android works as well.

```html
<h:head>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="preRenderView"
            listener="#{bookingController.preRenderView}" />
    </f:metadata>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="frmLT">
        <!-- Timeline -->
        <p:timeline id="timeline" value="#{bookingManagedBean.timeLineModel}"
            widgetVar="wvTimeline" editable="true" eventMargin="10"
            eventMarginAxis="0" start="#{bookingManagedBean.startDate}"
            end="#{bookingManagedBean.endDate}" showNavigation="#{true}"
            showButtonNew="true" axisOnTop="true" stackEvents="false">
            <p:ajax event="add" listener="#{bookingController.addEvent}"
                update="bookingForm timeline" />
        </p:timeline>
    </h:form>

    <h:form id="bookingForm">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <p:outputLabel value="Selected date:" for="selectedDate" />
            <p:calendar id="selectedDate" readonlyInput="true"
                value="#{bookingManagedBean.selectedEvent.startDate}">
            </p:calendar>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.primefaces.event.timeline.TimelineAddEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.timeline.TimelineEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "bookingController")
@RequestScoped
public class BookingController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @ManagedProperty("#{bookingManagedBean}")
    private BookingManagedBean bookingManagedBean;

    public BookingController() {
    }

    public void preRenderView() {
        if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {

            bookingManagedBean.setStartDate(new Date());

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(bookingManagedBean.getStartDate());
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
            bookingManagedBean.setEndDate(calendar.getTime());

            TimelineEvent demoEvent = new TimelineEvent("Demo Event", new Date(), false, "Demo Group");
            bookingManagedBean.getTimeLineModel().add(demoEvent);
        }
    }

    public void addEvent(TimelineAddEvent addEvent) {
        bookingManagedBean
            .setSelectedEvent(new TimelineEvent("New Event", addEvent.getStartDate(), false, addEvent.getGroup()));
        bookingManagedBean.getTimeLineModel().add(bookingManagedBean.getSelectedEvent());
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.model.timeline.TimelineEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.timeline.TimelineModel;

@ManagedBean(name = "bookingManagedBean")
@ViewScoped
public class BookingManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private TimelineModel timeLineModel;

    private TimelineEvent selectedEvent;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.timeLineModel = new TimelineModel();
    }

    public BookingManagedBean() {
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

The captured date should fire the ajax "add" event, but instead is giving me the mentioned exception.

```sh
feb 19, 2019 5:54:57 PM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
INFORMACIÓN: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NaN"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NaN"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803)
    at org.primefaces.util.DateUtils.toUtcDate(DateUtils.java:29)
    at org.primefaces.component.timeline.Timeline.queueEvent(Timeline.java:558)
    at org.primefaces.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorRenderer.decode(AjaxBehaviorRenderer.java:47)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorBase.decode(ClientBehaviorBase.java:132)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.decodeBehaviors(CoreRenderer.java:559)
    at org.primefaces.component.timeline.TimelineRenderer.decode(TimelineRenderer.java:41)
```

Comment: Please analyze the stacktrace and investigate what is actually happening (debug network traffic) that is different from using a normal desktop browser. And if you have errors, please create a [mcve] like requested in [ask] so other that want to try to reproduce can do that easily. And please also post version info. For all we know, you are using PrimeFaces 3.5 or some other old version.

Comment: Could be related to this: https://github.com/almende/chap-links-library/issues/334  But yes if you can get a JS stacktrace of WHERE the NAN is happening it will help us greatly.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comments, I tried to improve the question, hope you can help me.